# How use artisan with Lumen and Valet?

Tags: php, lumen, laravel-artisan, laravel-valet

I'd like to use Lumen with Valet. I already install a fresh installation of Lumen and everything is ok. When I tried to use artisan (and renamed .env.example into .env like documentation says) console says me that I need Memcache. So I did:

```
brew install php70-memcache --build-from-source --HEAD
```

And after it console give me:

```
[RuntimeException]           
No Memcached servers added.
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `CACHE_DRIVER` value to `file` or `array`, that worked for me

`CACHE_DRIVER=file`

Comment: If this worked for you. Please mark this answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Your config is setup to look for memcached. In your `.env` file, comment out or remove the line:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
```

Then run `artisan` again.

**Update**

Try restarting your server and see if that helps.

Comment: What artisan commend are you trying to run?

Comment: Just php artisan

Comment: Can you post your .env file up (removing sensitive details)?

Comment: Sure: APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

Comment: Try restarting your server and see if that helps.